# Flutter state management, trigger state change from outside widget tree

Tags: flutter, state, provider

I have the following components:

1. DataModel (a class that holds some variables), in my case a singleton
2. Several screens, that reflects this DataModel
3. Several triggers that update the DataModel, two of them are non-UI: response from HTTP call and data arriving from WebSocket

I'm trying to achieve the following flow in Flutter:
listen to data from HTTP response / WebSocket -> update DataModel (state change) -> update UI

I've read about different approaches to state management (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options), and tried some of them (like Provider).
My main issue is that I can't figure out how to update my DataModel from non-UI components (like HTTP response / WebSocket), since I need to include a context (which is really irrelevant in that case) in order to update my DataModel, something like this:

```
Provider.of<DataModel>(context).onUpdate(myDataModel)
```

What is the simplest approach to achieve this task (update DataModel -> trigger UI update)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) package. Riverpod is from the creator of Provider and can be considered as a rewrite of provider to make improvements that would be otherwise impossible. Riverpod doesn't depend on Flutter so it is able to listen to providers without a BuildContext.

Comment: Went over the doc and the examples.
Looking for a simple example, where the watched object is a class (with properties and methods), and doesn't extend a List (or something similar). Also - can't figure out how to declare a provider which will be accessible to any class / widget in my project: final testData = Provider((_) => TestData());

Comment: I'll request you to checkout the example that answers both your questions: https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/tree/master/examples/todos https://Rivepod.dev has very good documentation. (Ans:1) On this page you can see how to create a class that extends StateNotifies => https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/master/examples/todos/lib/todo.dart (Ans:2) The most common way to declare Provider is to declare them as global constant like so:
final myProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return MyValue();
}); Do not be afraid by the global aspect of providers. Providers are fully immutable.

Comment: I also recommend you watch the following videos, you will have very good knowledge of Riverpod after watching first two, but watch all, you'll learn a lot (a) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVspNESSess (b) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHJM5pd1yF4 (c) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttUNVsIl1tM (d) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atwWbkBdepE (e) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls8Jm-viQkc

Comment: Thanks for the videos: they do add a lot of info.
As for question 2 (unrelated to state management): if I declare final int temp = 1; in main.dart, how do I access it from another class / widget?

Comment: If final int temp = 1; has global scope then just import main.dart in the library (file) that you wish to access the it from